# convert comma separated values into multi column table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to convert comma separated list into multi column table and appreciate if you can help me.

**INPUT**

```
[aaa,111],[bbb,222],[ccc,333],[ddd,444]
```

**Desired OUTPUT**

```
col1      col2
aaa       111
bbb       222
ccc       333
ddd       444
```

Comment: What version of sql-server?  There are built in functions that can do that easily in 2016, SPLIT()

Comment: sql server 2012, yeh I am aware of SPLIT in SS 2016, but could not use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rather simple approach to transform this into XML directly:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='[aaa,111],[bbb,222],[ccc,333],[ddd,444]';

--This will do some replacements to transform your string to XML:
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,'],[','</y></x><x><y>'),',','</y><y>') + '</y></x>',']',''),'[','') AS XML);
```

This is the result

```
<x>
  <y>aaa</y>
  <y>111</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>bbb</y>
  <y>222</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>ccc</y>
  <y>333</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>ddd</y>
  <y>444</y>
</x>
```

You can use this like here to retrieve your values (type-safe!):

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='[aaa,111],[bbb,222],[ccc,333],[ddd,444]';

SELECT x.value('y[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Column1
      ,x.value('y[2]/text()[1]','int') AS Column2
FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,'],[','</y></x><x><y>'),',','</y><y>') + '</y></x>',']',''),'[','') AS XML)
) tbl(CastedToXml)
CROSS APPLY CastedToXml.nodes('/x') A(x);
```

The result

```
Column1 Column2
aaa     111
bbb     222
ccc     333
ddd     444
```

Comment: thanks @shnugo this works for me, I will try testing wrap this inside an inline function

Answer (score 1):

Use a string split function and split first on `],[` to get the rows.   Then split each row on `,` to get the columns.

Comment: and replace('[','')

Answer (score 1):

If open to a helper function.

Tired of extracting strings (left,right,charindex,patindex,etc), I modified a parse/split function to accept two non-like delimiters.  In your case a `[` and a `]`

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '[aaa,111],[bbb,222],[ccc,333],[ddd,444]'

Select Col1 = left(RetVal,NullIf(charindex(',',RetVal),0)-1)
      ,Col2 = stuff(RetVal,1,NullIf(charindex(',',RetVal),0),'')
 From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'[',']')
```

**Returns**

```
Col1   Col2
aaa    111
bbb    222
ccc    333
ddd    444
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Just for fun, try

```
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'[',']')
```

You'll get... then we just parse RetVal

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1       2       aaa,111
2       12      bbb,222
3       22      ccc,333
4       32      ddd,444
```

Comment: What, no XML ? :-)